# Taking Backup Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Im using Mysql database and visual basic 2010. In my program i put a button named 'Take the back up of the Database' the code is here:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Kontrol As Boolean
    Dim Dongu As Integer
    Dim Yolumuz As String
    Dim SuAnkiYil As String
    Dim GecilecekYil As String

    Try
    SuAnkiYil = Trim(Me.BilgilerDataGridView.Rows(5).Cells(1).Value)
    GecilecekYil = Trim(ArsivDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value)
    Yolumuz = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Yolumuz & "/Arsiv/" & SuAnkiYil)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Yolumuz & "/Database1.mdf", Yolumuz & "/Arsiv/" & SuAnkiYil & "/Database1.mdf")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Yolumuz & "/Database1_log.ldf", Yolumuz & "/Arsiv/" & SuAnkiYil & "/Database1_log.ldf")

    Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
    End Try
```

when i push the button there becomes an error. "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"
is there any way to make program to stop to use the database? i think if we success this, error will fix. Can you please share your opinion?

Comment: You should use the built-in facilities of your database engine to do a backup. The file is in use because your database engine is keeping the file open.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that the *.mdf file is being used by a database engine - probably your MySQL Server.

There are a few articles out there explaining how to correctly backup a MySQL Database.

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-MySQL-Database/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/vblanguage/thread/2047bf48-69c4-403a-893c-c36e906a870e

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19537-MySQL-Database-Backup-Restore-from-C-NET.aspx

Comment: I read them. Thanks but the nothing changed. I must find the way to release the database. Thenk you again for your help.